# How do you add an enum type to a class that has normal instance variables?

Tags: java, enums

```
public class Car
{

    public enum User { "user", "computer", "na" };

    private char car;
    private final User user;
    private boolean call;

    public Car(char object, User user, boolean call)
    {
        this.car = car;
        this.user = user;
        this.call = call;
    }

        public User getUser()
        {
        return user;
        }

    public void setUser(User user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

When I try to compile, I get the following:

error: expected

error: ',', '}', or ';' expected

error: '}' expected

Comment: Don't add the semicolon after the `enum`.

Comment: u need to accept one answer when you thing u got d answer.

Answer (score 5):

Do not use quotes:

```
public enum User { user, computer, na };
```

Comment: Also, consider using a `private enum` unless you want everyone to be able to use the `enum`.

Comment: how do I initialize a new class object?

Comment: `new Car('0', User.computer, false)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
private enum User { USER, COMPUTER, NA }
```

Also, to allow assignment, remove the `final` keyword from the declaration of `user`:

```
private User user;
```

To create a new `Car`, you could then use:

```
new Car('A', User.COMPUTER, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem are the double quotes in:

```
public enum User { "user", "computer", "na" };
```

Remove them:

```
public enum User { user, computer, na };
```